# Can I install Powershell 4 side by side with Powershell 3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have Powershell 3 installed on my box.

I need to test some scripts with Powershell 4 but I want to continue to run some of my scripts that are tested under Powershell 3 and I do not want to break something by installing Powershell 4.

**QUESTION**:Is it possible to open a Powershell sessions under Powershell version 3 (or even 2 if needed) despite I have installed Powershell 4?

Comment: See this almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554993/can-you-mimic-powershell-v3-once-you-have-installed-v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Starting with V3, you could open a powershell session for a downlevel version using the -Version parameter.

```
-Version
    Starts the specified version of Windows PowerShell.
    Enter a version number with the parameter, such as "-version 2.0".
```

So running

```
Powershell.exe -Version 2
```

will start a session that can be used to run/test a V2 script.

Comment: If Windows PowerShell 3.0 is installed on the computer, valid values are "2.0" and "3.0". The default value is "3.0".
If Windows PowerShell 3.0 is not installed, the only valid value is "2.0". Other values are ignored.

Comment: What does this actually do? Does it actually run the PS version specified, or is this some kind of compatibility mode implemented in the newer version?

Comment: Answer is incorrect. The only valid values for `-Version` are `2` and `3`, all other numbers get rounded to those two. If user have higher PS versions installed like 4.0 or 5.0, `-Version 3` represent those versions, because they are extensions to Version 3 runtime.

Answer (score 6):

When you have the Windows Management Framework Core 4.0 package installed, you can run PowerShell version 2.0, but not 3.0. Use the `-version 2.0` parameter to launch PowerShell v2.

See this TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847899.aspx

Also see the `help about_powershell.exe` help documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553275.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To frame the information in [user189198's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838793/45375) a bit differently, with the benefit of hindsight:

- No, **v3 can *not* run alongside v4, v5, or v5.1**, the latest and *last* version of ***Windows PowerShell***.

  - **Only *one* of these versions can be installed**.
- In v3, v4, v5, and v5.1, **the *only* version you can run *alongside* is v2.**

  - However, doing so **requires .NET Framework 2.0** to be installed (v2.0.50727, per the error message you get if it isn't installed), which is no longer a given in recent versions of Windows (which come with Windows PowerShell v5.1), where you **may have to install it manually**.

By contrast, there are ***no* limitations** on what versions of **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** - the modern, install-on-demand, cross-platform successor to the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only *Windows PowerShell* - you can install and run alongside each other.