# Remote connection always to Powershell 5 - how to connect to Powershell 7?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I try to remotely connect to multiple computers where both versions of Powershell installed: 5.1 and 7.3. Everything goes fine, and I am connected, but always to **old Powershell version 5.1**.

What I should do to connect to **newer Powershell 7.3** ?

This is the connection command:

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName server01 `
                      -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) `
                      -Credential $cred

Enter-PSSession -Session $sess
```

P.S. I set `Enable-PSRemoting` on both versions and I actually trying to connect from Powershell 7.3

Comment: You need to modify PSModulePath. From Start Button : Type Environmental Variables and select "Edit Environmental Variables"  You can have more than one path so you can put 7.3 before 5.1 and have both so if cmdlet is not in 7.3 it will use the older version in 5.3.

Comment: @jdweng I did what you suggest.... It seems it does not do any difference... Could you send me your PATH ?

Comment: It won't help to see my path.  Every machine is different.  How are you checking the PowerShell Version?  Did you use this : https://winaero.com/find-powershell-version-windows/

Comment: The Edit Environmental Variables has two sections.  User and System.  The user section take priority over system.  When applications are installed there is usually an option to install for single user or all users.  You may of only installed the new powershell for single user and not all users.

Comment: Yes - I check version of Powershell by running `$PSVersionTable` and in remote session it always shows v5.1.  Sorry - all recommendation that give didn't help me to connect to Powershell v7.3 - it is always 5.1. May be there's something else in your computer configured ?

Comment: PowerShell is in the c:\windows\system32 folder and new version would need to be placed in same location.  Use following to run a different version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838469/can-i-install-powershell-4-side-by-side-with-powershell-3?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng - considering the accepted and correct answer below - are you sure that what you suggested will lead us to solve my question ? Are you 100% sure that *you* could connect between Powershell 7.3 based machines ? Strange....

Comment: How are you going to make sure you run Power Shell v7.2.7 on remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default session configurations by using the `$PSSessionConfigurationName` preference variable:

```
$PSSessionConfigurationName = 'PowerShell.7';
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName server01 
                      -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck)
                      -Credential $cred;
Enter-PSSession -Session $sess;
```

You can find more details [about Session Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_session_configurations?view=powershell-7.3#main) in the docs.

Comment: WOW !! Cool ! Thanks ! I think this is exactly what I need but for some reason I started to receive an error:
`New-PSSession: [server01] Connecting to remote server server01 failed with the following error message : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`
Any ideas what I need to install ?

Comment: I installed .NET Core 6 and 7 (on both computers) and still getting this error

Comment: That's a known issue in the latest PowerShell version I forgot to mention (see [#18671](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18671)). Use Power Shell v7.2.7 on the remote machine and you should be fine.