# Powershell Import module results in unexpected path

Tags: powershell, module

I have a simple layout:

```
C:\scripts\script.ps1
C:\scripts\my_file.json
C:\scripts\modules\FileTools.psm1
```

My module looks like this:

```
function Get-JsonFile {
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [string]$FileName
  )
  $JsonHashMap = Get-Content -Raw $Filename | ConvertFrom-Json
  return $JsonHashMap
}
```

When I import this module to use it to load my jsonfile

```
Import-Module .\modules\FileTools.psm1
$stuff = Get-JsonFile -FileName $PSScriptRoot\my_file.json
```

I have to pass `$PSScriptRoot` to the -FileName parameter, otherwise the module uses a relative path resulting in it not being able to find the file.  (The module looks for the file in the C:\scripts\modules directory).

I think I can appreciate why this works in this way, but cant seem to find the "proper" way of allowing the module to be imported and then called with a relative path reference to make it easier to use.  So I want to do:

```
Import-Module .\modules\FileTools.psm1
$stuff = Get-JsonFile -FileName my_file.json
```

But I want to avoid having a relative path reference in the module: that is to say I want to avoid using `..\$Filename` as the module might not always be a subdirectory.  I expect I have missed something fundamental!  How do I solve this?

Comment: You have already found the correct way to solve it by using `$PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, gave the answer, for the cause: [Functions from a module don't run in a child scope of the calling scope. Modules have their own session state that's linked to the global scope. All module code runs in a module-specific hierarchy of scopes that has its own root scope.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#parent-and-child-scopes)

Comment: Have a look at the `$env:PSModulePath` environment variable. It allows you to add base directory of your modules to the search path, so you don't need to specify the module path in `Import-Module` call. Even better, you don't have to use `Import-Module` at all! This requires that you use the standard module directory structure, with versioned sub folder and module manifest, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416988/7571258 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.3