# Structuring a PowerShell library

Tags: powershell

## Example library

Here's a very simple PowerShell library, `xyz`.

`lib.ps1` provides 3 helper functions.

`script-a.ps` uses 2 of the functions

`script-b.ps` uses 2 of the functions

## Source of the files

Here's the layout and file contents:

[image]

[image]

## Observations

As you can see, it's extremely naively laid out.

The scripts are explicitly sourcing `lib.ps`.

The scripts only work if run from the `xyz` directory.

## Question

What's the recommended way to structure this library?

## Update

Here's one approach where I turn `lib.ps1` into a module.

Then each script imports the module, referring to `$PSScriptRoot` in the path, so the scripts work when run from anywhere.

[image]

[image]

## Update script-c.ps1

Suppose there is a `script-c.ps1` that uses `script-a.ps` and `script-b.ps1`:

[image]

As you can see, it's using explicit paths.

What would be a good way to incorporate `script-c.ps1` in a way that it can be run from any directory?

Here's one variation that appears to work, but seems a bit awkward due to the explicit references to `$PSScriptRoot` when calling the scripts:

[image]

Comment: Modify the environmental variable PSModulePath.  From start button type Edit Environmental Variables for your Account.

Comment: Modules (*.psm1) that can be found through `$env:PSModulePath` support implicit loading, that is you don't even need to call `Import-Module` anymore. Just calling an exported function defined in the module, implicitly loads the module. There is more administrative overhead though, because you have to create a module manifest and put the files in a specific directory structure. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_module_manifests

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416988/7571258) I'm showing a way to make modules portable (i. e. using them without installing them, while still getting benefits like implicit loading).