# Functions not available after loading module

Tags: powershell, import, module

In a script I import two modules. With the -Verbose and - Force parameters the verbose report looks fine:

```
>Module Path is E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\ModDS_USB_dev.psm1

VERBOSE: Loading module from path 
'E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\ModDS_USB_dev.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Test-USBModuleLoaded'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Confirm-USB_Mounted'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Dismount-USB'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-DriveLetter'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Confirm-USB_Mounted'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Dismount-USB'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-DriveLetter'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Test-USBModuleLoaded'.
```

To double check I then run Get-Module and receive the following report which seems to state the all the functions in the module have been correctly imported:

```
>
Script     4.8.5      Logging                             {Add-LoggingLevel, Add-LoggingTarget, Get-LoggingAvailableTarge...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}         
Script     0.0        ModDS_FileMgt02_dev                 {Backup_Folder, Import-Modules, Remove-OldBackups, Test-FileMgt...
Script     0.0        ModDS_Misc_dev                      {Convert-RawFiles, Get-UserInput, Get-UserInputViaForm, Initial...
Script     0.0        ModDS_USB_dev                       {Confirm-USB_Mounted, Dismount-USB, Get-DriveLetter, Test-USBMo...
```

But when I try to call any of the USB module functions from the script I get the message:

```
Test-USBModuleLoaded : The term 'Test-USBModuleLoaded' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\UnloadImagesSD_dev.ps1:148 char:1
+ Test-USBModuleLoaded
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-USBModuleLoaded:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Confirm-USB_Mounted : The term 'Confirm-USB_Mounted' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\UnloadImagesSD_dev.ps1:159 char:1
+ Confirm-USB_Mounted    #  in module ModDS_USB_dev. This check could b ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Confirm-USB_Mounted:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The calling script is:

```
Test-USBModuleLoaded
Confirm-USB_Mounted
```

Anybody any idea how a successfully imported module and its functions is not recognised when called?

Comment: What do you get if you run:
`Get-Command -Module 'ModDS_USB_dev'`

Have you also created a Manifest for the module, like the example at the bottom of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @KG-DROID     Get-Command -Module 'ModDS_USB_dev'  shows the details and code of all the functions in ModDS_USB_dev.  So all the functions seem to be available to Get-Command but not to their function call in the main script

Comment: @KG-DROID, I have read the page and it tells me how to create a manifest but not why I should and how it would solve my problem.

Comment: That maybe why its not working if you don't have a manifest, I have personally never made a module without a manifest so cant say for sure its that but its worth trying, it allows you to give detail to the module, like its version number, author etc, and also which functions you want to export from the module. If you also list your functions in that FunctionsToExport field, then if you place the module in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules, then it will also self import whenever you launch powershell. Most of the fields in the manifest can be left empty too, if you dont need them.

Comment: Does the calling script contain an explicit `Import-Module E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\ModDS_USB_dev.psm1` call at the top? @KG-DROID, while using a manifest is advisable, you don't strictly need one: by default, all functions and aliases defined in a `.psm1` file are exported.

Comment: @mklement0, no the top level script does not contain an Import-Module; it calls another module which calls the USB module. I think you may have it; I will experiment.

Comment: @mklement0 so moving the Import-Module instruction from another already-imported module to the top level script solves the problem. So I wonder if it is a scoping problem?
Whilst reading up on the subject I discovered that, with Powershell V3 onwards, modules dont need to be imported at all; providing they are installed in either of:
C:\Users\David\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
I had not been installing modules in these directories because then a system rebuild would lose my modules. I might need to rethink that.

Comment: There is a way without installing the modules. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416988/7571258 -- tl;dr: add your local modules directory to the `PSModulePath` environment variable, e. g. `$env:PSModulePath = "$PSScriptRoot\modules;$env:PSModulePath"`

Comment: @zett42 but MicroSoft warn that "Once you have added the path to PSModulePath, you should broadcast an environment message about the change. Broadcasting the change allows other applications, such as the shell, to pick up the change. To broadcast the change, have your product installation code send a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with lParam set to the string "Environment". Be sure to send the message after your module installation code has updated PSModulePath."
I dont have a product installation code AFAIK, so cannot do that.

Comment: @Davy Broadcasting the message isn't needed when only your own code is using the modules. By assigning to `$env:PSModulePath` you are only modifying the module search path privately, for the current PowerShell session and no other processes are affected. So sending the message wouldn't do any good.