# Install Powershell module as normal user

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I want to use the `Get-ADUser` module to retrieve data from the AD domain.

Non-Administrator permissions in the directory are sufficient to perform that action.

Locally, Administrator permissions are necessary to install to install the module as part of `Windows Remote Server Administration Tools` like so:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT.ActiveDirectory* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Is there a way to make the `Get-ADUser` module available to my local user without local Administrator permissions?

Comment: You can make a PowerShell module portable, to load it from a directory relative to your script, without having to install it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416988/7571258

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that worked for me:

1. Find nuget (.nupkg) file for ActiveDirectory module (used to be available to download from PowershellGallery, but it's not there anymore) and extract it.
2. Copy AD module install directory from a server when the module is installed. That's assuming you have rights on other servers, or somebody can copy it for you.

Then you can `Import-Module` from this extracted/copied folder.

You can even make the module work on Windows 10:

1. Copy `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll` to module location. Normally it's installed with RSAT, you can get it from GAC on a server when AD module is installed.
2. Open ActiveDirectory.psd1
3. Change `RequiredAssemblies="Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management` to `RequiredAssemblies='.\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll'`

Comment: I have copied the DLL from a downloaded eval VM where I've installed RSAT. After 'Import-Module' I can use it, in principle. All properties of the user objects are listed, but for some strange reason, I now cannot access most of them, which was definitely possible with normal user permissions when the module was installed by regular means. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @MichaelB.Ortiz Please show some examples