# Invoke-WebRequest with PScredentials

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a file from an external HTTPS site.  My code below works a treat in POSH 3.0, but in POSH 4.0, not so much.  The message I get is below.  Anyone experiencing the same issue, know how to resolve this or a workaround?

*Invoke-WebRequest :

Authentication Required.

You must be authenticated to access this URL.

URL: https://www.mywebsite.com

User name:

At line:4 char:1

+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mywebsite.com/report.pdf ...

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest)  [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand*

```
$pw = ConvertTo-Securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "myPWD"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ("myUser",$pw)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mywebsite.com/report.pdf -Credential $cred -OutFile C:\report.pdf
```

Comment: And yes, the credentials are correct.  I can access the site from my browser.  :)

Comment: if you run with -Debug do you get any extra clues?

Comment: Exact same results unfortunately.

Comment: This posts suggests the behavior should be the same in V3 or V4.   Does anyone get similar results?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554993/can-you-mimic-powershell-v3-once-you-have-installed-v4

Comment: Go download Fiddler and examine the RAW Request between using v3 and v4 and see if you can spot any differences.

Comment: Fiddler only tells me this:

Comment: V4  
HTTP/1.1 0 Connection passed to Gateway - Result unknown  
EndTime: 07:26:33.000  

V3  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Date: Fri, 02 May 2014 14:28:55 GMT  
Server: Apache  
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate  
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI IVA IVD OUR IND INT"  
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Apr 2014 09:32:46 GMT  
ETag: "377"  
Accept-Ranges: bytes  
Content-Length: 887  
Content-Type: application/zip  
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive  
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: It looks like the credentials are passing in correctly.  I'll see about doing some testing with this.

Comment: So after doing more testing, I've found it is not a POSH 3.0 v POSH 4.0.  I actually cannot get it to work on any other workstation or server.  I thought it may be a web filter issue (co-existence during migration), but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Made sure they were on the same subnet as my laptop, same POSH version.  I'm at my wits end with this.

Answer (score 1):

So I found that even though I could access the website and retrieve my content with my browser, the McAfee Web Gateway was preventing Powershell from doing the same thing.  Once we whitelisted the URL, BOOM, no problems.  Thanks everyone for the additional ideas in helping me troubleshoot this!